# CSS desktop/mobile button styling

Tags: css, button

I styled some CSS buttons, and they look great, but when I open the page on mobile, they look bad and don't use the defined styles.  How does one typically maintain the styling of buttons in CSS across all devices?

Here's my code for the buttons that looked good in the browser:

```
input[type="button"]
{
width: 416px;
border: none;
color: #fff;
font-size: 1em;
padding: .5em;
margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
border-radius: 3px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 40px;
background: #00aeff;
}

input[type="button"]:hover
{
background: #00a0db;
}
```

But this is what it actually looked like on different pages on mobile.
[image]

Comment: Define "hideous"? Also some code and perhaps a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which shows what is happening would be useful.

Comment: @Cassidy Williams Try using `@media query` for this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic bullet. Make sure that your styles have proper platform-specific directives (ie -webkit-) and, most importantly, are supported on the platforms that are acting up.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the font-size..Try setting px value for the font..it should be Ok..

like

```
input[type="button"]
{
  font-size:14px;
}
```